# What is the best way to authenticate user with node and angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am doing a project on the node with the angles and Mysql, I want to use the user data from the Mysql database but what is the best way of user authentication with node?

I'm sorry for my English

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a **book**, **tool**, **software library**, **tutorial** or other **off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: For windows, I have every ajax call to the server send credentials. Then I use iisnode so you can elevate enviroment variables into the node app. The node app can then use those credentials sent. Then things like node-activedirectory can do ldap queries to active directory to check for premissions. For mysql I use node-mysql, but alot of people seem to like sequelize these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several authentication schemes, which you select depends on the objectives of your application. Many of these schemes or strategies are implemented in [passport module](http://passportjs.org/docs)